# How to enable Weblogic managed server ResolveDNSName?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, mbeans

I have patched **weblogic 12.2.1.4.0** with `30970477;WLS PATCH SET UPDATE 12.2.1.4.200228` and now cannot start managed1.

managed1 logs contains `Cannot resolve ClusterAddress: wlnode1:7101`

```
<Info> <Cluster> <wladminvip> <managed1> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <WL-000101> <Cannot resolve ClusterAddress: wlnode1:7101>
```

.....

```
<Warning> <Security> <wladminvip> <managed1> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <[]> <BEA-000000> <PAF - Error during MBeanServer connection: JNDI subsystem is not ready for use >
```

In the network initialization section there is `ResolveDNSName Enabled     false`

```
<BEA-000570> <Network Configuration for Channel "managed1"
 Listen Address          wlnode1:7101
 Public Address          N/A
 Http Enabled            true
 Tunneling Enabled       true
 Outbound Enabled        false
 Admin Traffic Enabled   true 
ResolveDNSName Enabled     false>
```

My question is where `ResolveDNSName` parameter has been defined and how can I enable it?

Comment: I have a question, are you sure this is caused by the patch? I mean, I have faced situations like this. However, it was caused by a change applied previously, an operator's error, file corruption, etc. that is uncovered after restarting the system. Could you try recovering the backup to see whether it fixes the issue or not? Keep in mind a patch modifies the product, but it does not modify the configuration.

Comment: You have attached INFO and WARNING messages. Could you attach messages from ".out" log file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit setDomainEnv.sh file and append to the JAVA_OPTIONS (or add it to start up options if you are starting Admin Server using Node Manager)

-Dweblogic.ResolveDNSName=true

2. Restart Admin Server